# Is there a way to remove white lines over a <table> in Outlook?

Tags: html, css, outlook

I tried to remove these white lines appearing just over 3 of my 5 content tables (all coded the same) but can't find a way to fix it.
Can anyone help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>Your Weekly IC-Newsletter</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <!--[if gte mso 9]>
      <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG/>
          <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      </xml>
    <![endif]-->
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

  <!--[if !mso]>

      <!-->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

  <!--<![endif]-->

  <style type="text/css">
  h2 {
      font-family: 'Arial Black';
      font-size: 24pt;
      color: #005F64;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    h3 {
      font-family: 'Arial Regular';
      font-size: 18pt;
      text-align: left;
    }
    
    p {
      font-family: 'Arial Regular';
      font-size: 11pt;
      color: #000000;
      text-align: left;
      -mso-line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    table,
    td,
    tr {
      vertical-align: top;
      border-collapse: collapse !important;
      padding: 0;
      align: center;
    }
    
    .img {
      float: right;
      width: 50px;
    }
    
    .Wrapper {
      width: 800px;
      align: center;
      background-color: ;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    
    .content {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      width: 750px;
      align: center;
      background-color: ;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .Textblock {
      background-color: #ffffff;
      border-top: 5px solid #005F64;
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .Textblock_inner {
      padding-left: 30px;
      padding-right: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .spacer {
      height: 25px !important;
      margin: 0 !important;
      padding: 0 !important;
      padding-top: 20px !important;
    }
  }
  .Footer {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
  }
  .icon {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body style="margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color:#4A4A49;">
  <table style="line-height: inherit; table-layout: fixed; vertical-align: top; min-width: 400px; Margin: 0 auto;
                                border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
                                width: 100%;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="100%" bgcolor="#4A4A49" valign="top">
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0;" align="center">
        <table class="Wrapper">
          <tr>
            <td align="center">
              <table class="Header">
                <tr>
                  <td marign-top="30px" margin-left="30px" padding-left="30px" padding-top="30px" align="center">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

              <table class="content">
                <tr>
                  <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;" align="center">
                    <table class="spacer">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px; -mso-line-height:20px;">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="Textblock">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="Textblock_inner">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="padding-top:45px">
                                <h2>ICG Management Information</h2>
                              </td>
                              <td style="padding-top:0px">
                                <img class="" src="https://assets.website-files.com/59db627ebcf39900019401dd/5de790c665d48a54c6df5237_LOGO_IC.svg" width="100px" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <h3>Overall Situation</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Business Strategy</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Business Planning</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea r </p>
                                <h3>Shareholder / Investors</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. S </p>
                                <h3>Priorities next 3 month</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="spacer">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px; -mso-line-height:20px;"> </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="Textblock">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="Textblock_inner">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="padding-top:45px">
                                <h2>Department Information</h2>
                              </td>
                              <td style="padding-top:0px">
                                <img class="" src="https://assets.website-files.com/59db627ebcf39900019401dd/5de790c665d48a54c6df5237_LOGO_IC.svg" width="100px" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <h3>Acquisition</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Development</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet cli
                                </p>
                                <h3>Marketing & Sales</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Operations</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsu </p>
                                <h3>Asset and Property Management</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="spacer">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px; -mso-line-height:20px;">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="Textblock">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="Textblock_inner">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="padding-top:45px">
                                <h2>ICG Project Information</h2>
                              </td>
                              <td style="padding-top:0px">
                                <img class="" src="https://assets.website-files.com/59db627ebcf39900019401dd/5de790c665d48a54c6df5237_LOGO_IC.svg" width="100px" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <h3>Systems</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Processes</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Compliance</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="spacer">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px; -mso-line-height:20px;">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="Textblock">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="Textblock_inner">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="padding-top:45px">
                                <h2>ICG Organisation Information</h2>
                              </td>
                              <td style="padding-top:0px">
                                <img class="" src="https://assets.website-files.com/59db627ebcf39900019401dd/5de790c665d48a54c6df5237_LOGO_IC.svg" width="100px" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <h3>HR</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Legal</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Tax</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Accounting</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="spacer">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px; -mso-line-height:20px;">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="Textblock">
                      <tr>
                        <td class="Textblock_inner">
                          <table>
                            <tr>
                              <td style="padding-top:45px">
                                <h2>ICG Market Information</h2>
                              </td>
                              <td style="padding-top:0px">
                                <img class="" src="https://assets.website-files.com/59db627ebcf39900019401dd/5de790c665d48a54c6df5237_LOGO_IC.svg" width="100px" />
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                <h3>Student housing insights</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                                <h3>Professional housing insights</h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita
                                  kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
                                  voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. </p>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table class="spacer">
                      <tr>
                        <td height="30" style="font-size:30px; line-height:30px; -mso-line-height:30px;">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>

                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              <table class="Footer">
                <tr>
                  <td align="center" text-align="center">
                    <h4 text-align="center">For further information follow one of our news channels</h4>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center">
                    <table class="">
                      <tr>

                        <td class="icon">
                          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/the_fizz_/?hl=de" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-margin-right-alt:10px;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-light-instagram-48.png" alt="Instagram" style="display:block;margin-right:8px; mso-margin-right-alt:10px;" width="40" /></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="icon">
                          <a href="https://de-de.facebook.com/pg/THEFIZZ.Students/posts/" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-margin-right-alt:10px;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-light-facebook-48.png" alt="Facebook" style="display:block;margin-right:8px; mso-margin-right-alt:10px;" width="40" /></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="icon">
                          <a href="http://the-fizz.com" target="_blank" style="mso-line-height-rule: exactly;mso-margin-right-alt:10px;-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;"><img src="https://cdn-images.mailchimp.com/icons/social-block-v2/outline-light-link-48.png" alt="Website" style="display:block;margin-right:8px;  mso-margin-right-alt:10px;" width="40" /></a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vx9c3wgm/#&togetherjs=BIqB9absmi

Comment: I made you a snippet - I remove the wrapping <html></html>

Comment: What white lines are you referring to?

Comment: If I cut and paste the output into outlook, I possibly see `<table class="spacer">
                      <tbody><tr>
                        <td height="30" style="font-size:30px; line-height:30px; -mso-line-height:30px;">
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody></table>` as a white line